# MPMoviePlayerController Performance Hit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use MPMoviePlayerController because I want to play movie.

One question. When I create MPMoviePlayerController, the app stops a little.

This is my code:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieRestartCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

`

Why does the app stop?
Is this problem resolution the way?

Comment: With little stop u mean some milliseconds of black screen or the app just halts?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for `MPMoviePlayerController` you'll see that in the example they call `prepareToPlay` before even adding the movie player to the view.

I would add `[mediaPlayer prepareToPlay]` where you're setting up the player.

[MPMediaPlayback Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says:
    "to minimize playback delay, call this method before you call play"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use multi-threading functions.

`NSOperationQueue` is thread safe (you can add operations to it from different threads without the need for locks) and enables you to chain NSOperation objects together.

You can use following code snap to use them.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
NSBlockOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // your code here
}];

[queue addOperation:operation];
```

I hope that is helpful to you.